# how to make transition of stacked Divs. in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am trying to make "memory game" using html5, CSS3 and JS. I have completed the view and model part of this game and now trying to make the Controller. What i want is call a function i.e. flip in JS and want that function to perform transition instead of using hover effect of CSS3. Basically i am trying to follow [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_transition) approach.  I checked that flipping in css3 using hover as can be seen in sass code below, but for the game, the user decides where to click. For simplicity, i have concised the code in html5 since it repeats for all other divs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>I Don't Know</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="trapStyle.css">

</head>
<body>
   <div  class = "container" >

    <div class="sub1" >
    <div class="front" id="card1"  onclick="flip(card1)">card1</div>
    <div class="back" id="card1_1">what the hell?</div>
    </div>   <--sub1 Ends-->

    <div class="sub1">
    <div class="front" id="card2" onclick="flip(this)">card2</div>
    <div class="back" id="card2_2">what the hell?
    </div>   <--sub1 Ends-->

    </div>  <-- container Ends -->


    <script src ="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the SASS code for css

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 115px;
    width: 1150px;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: silver;

/* SUB-CONTAINER to stack two cards */
    .sub1 {
        width: 200px;  height: 200px;
        float:left; margin: 5px;

        .front {
            position:absolute;  width: 200px;  height: 200px;
            background-color: #498010;
            transform: perspective( 600px) rotateY(0deg);
            backface-visibility: hidden;
            transition: transform 0.5s linear 0s;
        }

        .back {
            position: absolute;  width: 200px;  height: 200px;
            float:left;   background-color: #689;
            transform: perspective( 600px) rotateY(180deg);
            backface-visibility: hidden;
            transition: transform 0.5s linear 0s;
        } 


    }

    .sub1:hover > .front {

/*    transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg); */
}

       .sub1:hover > .back {

    /* transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg); */
}

}
```

and JavaScript

```
function flip(front) {

    document.getElementById("front").style.transition = opacity 0.5s linear 0s;
    document.getElementById("front").style.opacity = 0;

}
```

Note: the link, above, is trying to pass id to JS function where the transition takes place. Exactly same is being done here, just to get input from user instead of just hovering, but nothing happens! I copy/pasted the link code in my editor and smooth transitions are performed but when it comes of my code, nothing! Could you tell me where is my flaw?

Comment: Change your CSS from .sub1:hover to .hovered. Then, add class name "hovered" in JS to the element that you want

Comment: comment in html is <!--sub1 Ends-->

Comment: @vals I don't know how to do that. [Here] (http://jsfiddle.net/Lahori/pmvqd2ps/1/) is my jsfiddle, if you could do that for me, I would be grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your CSS from the hover state to a class, for iunstance change .sub1:hover to .hovered:

```
 .container .hovered > .front {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg); }
  .container .hovered > .back {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg); }
```

And now, on click, add this class to the element clicked:

```
$(".sub1").click(function() {
   $(this).addClass ('hovered');   
})
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmvqd2ps/2/)

this function in javascript would be

```
function change(element) {
    element.className = element.className + " hovered";
}
```

provided that you send the element in the function call

```
onclick="change(this)"
```

[fiddle - function set only in the first div](http://jsfiddle.net/pmvqd2ps/7/)

Comment: i did that but nothing happens :(

Comment: Have you checked the fiddle ?

Comment: oh, I 'm sorry @vals, I didn't check that! Its working great! Thank you so much!

Comment: It does work in jsfiddle but not in here! I wonder if you could provide same solution in JS instead of jQuery?

Comment: Added example in javaScript